# How to get number of hits in server

Tags: linux, performance, apache

I want to create a tool, with which we can administer the server.There are two questions with in this question:

1. To administer access/hit rate of a server. That is to calculate how many times the server has been accessed from a particular time period and then may be generate some kind of graph to demonstrate the load at a particular time on a particular day.

   However i don't have any idea, how i can gather these information.

   A pretty vague idea is to

   - use a watch over access log(in case of apache) and then count the number of times the notification occurs and note down the time simultaneously
   - Parse access.log file every time and then generate the output(but access.log file can be very big, so not sure about this idea)

   I am familiar with apache and hence the above idea is based on apache's access log and i don't have idea about other like nginx etc.

   Hence i would like to know, if I can use the above procedure or is there any other way possible.
2. I would like to know when the server is reaching its limit. The idea of using top and then show the live result of cpu usage and ram usage via CPP

Comment: Why on earth would you tag this c++?

Comment: there are a lot of information about getting Linux usage info. You don't need to write any particular programs, just parse the logs, use netstat and get the CPU/Memory information from procfs.  I suggest that you do some research and when you have an issue with a particular aspect, you can ask questions here

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html + example of output http://www.apache.org/server-status and you can write your own module for apache or modify this one - everything is open-source.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Well reading log is one way as i suggested. But don't you think, that log file can become pretty big as during severe load, there may be tonnes request every second and each of them will make its way into log file, which may increase its size from few hundred MB's to may GB's. And then parsing the entire thing can make the entire operation pretty slow. Also Apache may have different log file, WAS may have its own, nginx may have its own(idk not sure). They may have their own logging style, timestamp style etc. So, am i suppose to write code for each kind?

Comment: Is there no way to write once and use it again and again or may be some kind of API's. I did note your way of getting CPU information. :)

Comment: the other way is to get the server itself to give you the stats.  have you looked at mod_status for apache?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor a web server the easiest way is probably to use some existing tool like webalizer.
http://www.webalizer.org/

To monitor other things like CPU and memory usage I would suggest snmpd together with some other tool like mrtg. http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

If you think that webalizer does not sample data often enough with its hourly statistics but the sample time of mrtg with 5 minutes would be better it is also possible to provide more data with snmpd by writing an snmpd extension. Such an extension could parse the apache log file with a rather small amount of code and give you all the graphing functionality for free from mrtg or some other tool processing snmp data.